# How can I obtain selected filenames clientside using a fileupload control without submitting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I can't find an existing answer so far, but here is my goal:

I'd like to use the asp.net fileupload control(or some other control you might suggest) to select a series of files.  WITHOUT submitting a form, i'd like the selected files to be displayed in a concatenated list of some sort.

Is this possible with the Fileupload control or do I have to use something else?  I've seen many answers involving submission then grabbing the filenames, but I don't want to take a trip to the server for that.  Just looking to grab the filenames when they're selected, all clientside.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `files` property. See the code below:

```js
function onInputChange(e) {
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $("#customInput").get(0).files.length; i++) {
      res += $("#customInput").get(0).files[i].name + "<br />";
    }
  
    $('#result').html(res);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="customInput" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple onchange="onInputChange(event)" />
<br /><br />
<div style="color:blue" id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me.  Also thanks to you who also answered.  Appreciate the help, all.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

**Javascript**

```
 function showFile() {
  var file = document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>");      
  var path = file.value;
  alert(path); 
}
```

**File Upload Control**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="showFile()"  />
```